# Array values check for occurrence in JavaScript (with Arrow functions?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know if at least one of my strings in `myArr` ends with ".min.js"...

using the [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) I maybe would be able to do this task [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1faxzcdk/1/):

```js
var myArr = ["one.min.js", "two.max.js"];

$(function(){
    var test = myArr.every(
        e=>e.match('.min.js$'));
    $("#2").text(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="1">This is the value:
    <div id="2">default value</div>
</div>
```

but,
- this return *false* because is true only for ALL the values (not just some),
- is still "experimental" (not really compatible with all versions of IE or Firefox)

Is there an elegant, effective and (at least IE9) "compatible" workaround to that?

Comment: Simply don't use ES6 when you need to support IE9?

Comment: I don't need to use Arrow functions. It was an example

Comment: I think there's an `Array.prototype.some ()` shim on the MDN documentation page for the same (and I'd argue you want to use `some` rather than `every`).

Comment: You should not use `match` with a string argument. Pass a regex instead, like `/\.min\.js$/` (which does what you actually want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `every` and replace the arrow function with a anonymous function expression:

```
var myArr = ["one.min.js", "two.max.js"];

$(function(){
    var test = myArr.some(function (e) {
        return e.match(/\.min\.js$/);
    });
    $("#2").text(test);
});
```

This way, you should be fully IE 9 compatible.

http://jsfiddle.net/1faxzcdk/4/